# Написать сниффер (WinPcap/socket ?) для перехвата конкретных фрагментов данных.

Tags: windows, сеть

Доброго времени суток. Возникла необходимость перехватить несколько строк из приложения для последующей обработки. С помощью Wireshark использую фильтр rtmpt.amf.string == "%username%", но как с помощью своей программы-сниффера автоматизировать фильтр пакетов по протоколу и регулярному выражению данных? С чего начать и как продолжить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Привет. я использую WinPcap + windump - все работает)только вот фильтра не могу найти чтобы сами пакеты фильтроватьесли что вот статья http://forum.antichat.ru/thread29744.html

Comment: Где то натыкался на консольную программу фильтр типа регулярки, вот найду дак думаю получу то что надо...